# Bash determine the difference between the highest and lowest variables

Tags: linux, bash, shell, variables, difference

As part of three variables I would like to determine is the difference between the highest and the lowest is less than a defined range.

```
Val1
Val2    
Val3
```

Until now, I got only two Val and I used something like :

```
let diff=${Val1}-${Val2}
```

Then, I calculate the absolute value of contains into "diff".

```
if [ "$diff" -ge 0 ]                    
then                                
    absval=$diff                        
else                                
    let "absval = (( 0 - $diff ))"      
fi
```

But now, what is the more efficient way to perfom this stuff ?

Answer (score 2):

Use `if` tests to compare the variables directly.

```
if [[ $Val1 -gt $Val2 ]]
then highest=$Val1
else highest=$Val2
fi

if [[ $Val3 -gt $highest ]]
then highest=$Val3
fi
```

If you have more variables, you can just keep doing this:

```
if [[ $Val4 -gt $highest ]]
then highest=$Val4
fi
```

Use similar steps with `-lt` to get the lowest value.

Another way to do it is to sort the values and then get the first and last lines of this:

```
sorted=$(printf "%s\n" $Var1 $Var2 $Var3 | sort -n)
highest=$(echo "$sorted" | tail -1)
lowest=$(echo "$sorted" | head -1)
diff=$(( highest - lowest ))
```

Comment: Thank Barmar, but I have to determine both the highest and the lowest variable. I can use if [[ $Val3 -lt $lowest ]]; then lowest=$Val3 fi and define lowest in the first else if but it is heavy, isn't ?

Comment: When I was writing my answer the question just asked how to get the highest, it didn't say anything about also needing the lowest.

Comment: Indeed, sorry for the update. Your solution returns head: invalid option -- '1'

Comment: Some versions of `head` and `tail` have different syntax. Maybe yours requires `head -n 1`

Answer (score 2):

Using awk if that is allowed

```
awk '{max=$1<max&&max~/./?max:$1;min=$1>min&&min~/./?min:$1}END{print max-min}' file
```

---

#### Input

> 1
> 2
> 10
> 5
> 3
> 9

#### Output

```
9
```

Answer (score 2):

The most efficient way (which, you must realize, may not be the *fastest* way for any particular input) is to iterate though the list and simply keep track of the smallest and largest number so far.

```
while read num; do
    if (( num > highest )); then highest=num; fi
    if (( num < lowest )); then lowest=num; fi
done <<EOF
Val1
Val2    
Val3
...
EOF

diff=$(( highest - lowest ))
```

In theory, sorting is not the most efficient way to find the highest and lowest, since you don't need to do the extra work to put *all* the numbers in order. (In practice, you may need a very large number of numbers before the O(n) algorithm in `bash` outperforms the O(n lg n) algorithm implemented by `sort` in C.)

Comment: `read` is extremely slow though as it needs to make a system call for every byte, its more than likely that using `sort` would be significantly faster even though the algorithm would need to do more work.My awk script in my answe does the same thing but is considerably quicker as it uses a buffer.

Comment: Indeed. Your answer is the best, which implements the optimal algorithm in a sane fashion :)

Comment: OP did ask for bash though so +1 :)

Answer (score 0):

If you can put them in a file, you can do it in a single command `sort -V <filename>`. This sorts them numerically . If you have lots of values to sort, this might be a better option with much less code.

Here is an example:

```
cat <filename>
1
2
10
5
3
9

sort -n <filename>
1
2
3
5
9
10
```

If you'd like to get the lowest and the highest numbers and the difference between them , you can do so like this.

```
result=$(sort -n <filename>)
high=$(echo "$result" | tail -1)
low=$(echo "$result" | head -1)
diff=`expr $high - $low`

echo "Highest is $high"
echo "Lowest is $low"
echo "Diff is $diff"
```

Comment: This is only half a solution. You still need to extract the highest and lowest values in order to compute their absolute difference.

Comment: @chepner Yes. I have updated the answer to include the complete ask.